# Where does Thor get his hammer when he's not using it?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, mjolnir

Does anyone know where Thor gets his hammer when he's not using it? The sky? A storage place in Asgard?

Comment: Where does he store his hammer when he's not using it or how does he get his hammer? There's a scene in _Thor: The Dark World_ I believe when he keeps falling through portals which shows the hammer coming to him and changing direction a few times. That _could_ be an answer here but its a bit unclear with your wording.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot where should I correct it?

Comment: Probably anywhere he wants. The only people who could steal it are people who wouldn't steal it.

Comment: @Elfvia What do you mean? If you're asking where he stores it, change get to store. If you're asking how it comes to him when he's not using it then it needs a significant edit.

Comment: When Thor isn't using Mjolnir, he keeps it tucked up cosy in a small makeshift bed in a drawer on his bedside table. [Seriously.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cb24kGrE1l4&t=1m35s)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite maybe it was just for that time, but what about Infinity War, Endgame, etc?

Comment: @Elfvia Mjolnir is destroyed prior to *Infinity War*, so he's not storing it *anywhere* in that film. He retrieves a past copy of Mjolnir from a parallel Asgard about midway through *Endgame*, but I'm not sure what happens to it after the final battle. I hope I'm not spoiling anything for you here.

Comment: @F1Krazy Cap takes it back with him.

Comment: Hammerspace? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammerspace

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: we don't know but probably anywhere he wants really.

#### Long answer

He can store Mjolnir anywhere he wants, it has an enchantment on it that means only those who are deemed worthy can lift it. If you are deemed worthy, it is highly unlikely you would try and steal it. In reality, he will obviously keep it close to hand so if he needs it in a hurry it won't take long to get to him.

> **Odin:** Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

This means he'll likely store it in his bedroom or an armoury nearby when on Asgard and similar in the Avengers HQ on Earth.

We do have at least 1 canonical example of him storing Mjolnir somewhere and that appears in *Thor: The Dark World* when he hangs it on a coat hook when entering an apartment.

If we consider the *Team Thor* mockumentary short films as canon then he stores it in his bedside table draw all tucked up.

[image: Mjolnir taking a nap]

During the same film we see Mjolnir around the apartment in various locations, such as the kitchen counter top so, as previously said, he just leaves it wherever he wants to really; it's not like anyone else can move it.

Of course though in reality he almost always has it with him and so doesn't need to store it anywhere. It's just something he takes with him when he goes out and about.

Comment: in *The Dark World* it would have been possible that Hela could have come in his apartment and got the hammer so he was defenseless. One quick question though - does that mean if he goes shopping or something, he takes the hammer with him...?

Comment: @Elfvia No it wouldn't because Odin was holding her back, plus as far as Thor is concerned she doesn't exist. For your question, we don't know because we never see him go shopping as far as I know... though to be fair I've only skimmed the Team Thor mockumentary so maybe they mention it at some point but I doubt it.

Comment: TheLethalCarrot oh, okay. I don't think they ever go shopping either, but I mean when they go to cafe's or something?

Comment: @Elfvia The only cafe like thing I can think of is The Avengers post credits scene in the Shawarma place but that's right after the battle so it's understandable he has Mjolnir with/near him. I mean we have little to no evidence on this so I'm not sure what you really want here.

Comment: @Elfvia He has Mjolnir with him in AoU when partying in Stark Tower too.

Comment: TheLethalCarrot oh. I was just wondering sorry if I confused you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101272/discussion-between-elfvia-and-thelethalcarrot).

Comment: Now Thor storing his hammer in his bedside in a comfy box is my headcanon.

Comment: In Ragnarok Thor puts the disguised Mjolnir in Dr. Strange's umbrella rack

Comment: @aherocalledFrog aye, though as that’s in disguise one could argue it’s not a normal case so I decided to leave it out of the examples.

Comment: So...is the coat hook worthy? :)

Comment: _Cell phone, wallet, keys, sunglasses, Mjolnir_ Yup, I'm ready to go for lunch...